# how to determine the extension of a file

Tags: android

I'm fetching byte array from server but don't know the exact extension of the file because that file could be .pdf / mp4 / docx / zip, so how would I know the exact extension after saving it to sdcard.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to reliably determine the file extension from the file contents. It's like trying to find out what was written on an envelope, if all you have is the letter itself.

You could *guess*, but that would be a difficult task (for example, a `docx` is also a `zip` file). There is specialized software for this (many operating systems include the [`file` tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)), and you might find a third-party library that you can use, but even if you do that, it's still a guess.

I'd rather concentrate on finding a way for the server to tell you the original file name in addition to the contents.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to determine the file extension right away.

However you can impose conditions for the specific file types like if the file extension is mp3 then do the certain task. For that you can use `FilenameFilter`.

Check the [how-to-find-all-files-with-certain-extension-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040197/how-to-find-all-files-with-certain-extension-on-android) for more information about it.

Comment: if I knew the extension I wouldn't post my question here, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If it is custom protocol, you should pass one(or more) byte of data type to the client side, then you get data and add extension on the client side according to the first byte(s). If it is http-like protocol, you can add some header to the answer. But it is need to do as on the serverside as well as on the clientside too.