# open specific files from within android app

Tags: android

As part of an app I'm writing, I need an ability to look for specific files, like .doc or .rtf, from within the app. After finding them, the app will store their adress or something like that, so that they could later be opened when necessary. The app wouldn't open them itself, it will use a different app for that. So, all I'm looking for is a way to browse for those files from within my app.

Answer (score 2):

As i understand you need to find files with given extension. For this approach you can use FileFilter. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040446/799799).

Comment: Thanks! I saw the answer you pointed to, they talk about a FileBrowser there. Is there some specific android object? Or do I need to look online nd find a good file browser for my app? I did some googling and couldn't find a browser that can be implemented in my app

Comment: @n00b programmer Actually i don't know something about android's internal filebrowser api or something like this. Maybe they mean third party application like Total Commander for android or ES File Explorer?